# Working with RTOS

Tags: embedded, rtos

I'm quite new to embedded field.i want to learn RTOS and apply it for any application .I have been searching in net for a while and i have been lost completely.

Is there a good place to start.

Comment: [This](http://www.techonline.com/education-training/fundamentals/4213896/Fundamentals-of--Real-Time-Operating-Systems) and [this](http://www.techonline.com/education-training/fundamentals/4228859/Fundamentals-of-Advanced-Real-Time-Operating-Systems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try one of the MicroC/OS books by Labrosse, which describe an example RTOS.  Or search the articles at [embedded.com](http://www.embedded.com).

Comment: I know the concepts ,but have not worked with it . any place where i can start of with ?

Comment: such as examples, mini project or something like that .i want to get an hands on experience on it .